# 500 mistakes in 500 pages

Tags: probability, statistics

In a book of 500 pages there are 500 mistakes. Find the probability that there are atmost 3 mistakes in a particular page.

The problem can be solved by using Binomial or Poisson Distribution.

However I want to solve it using the classical defination of probability.

Total no. of possible cases= $500^{500}$

No. of cases for 0 mistakes in ${i^{th}}$ page= $499^{500}$

No. of cases for 1 mistake in ${i^{th}}$ page= $500*499^{499}$

No. of cases for 2 mistakes in ${i^{th}}$ page= $500*499*498^{498}$

No. of cases for 3 mistakes in ${i^{th}}$ page= $500*499*498*497^{497}$

Is my procedure right?? Please explain if I am wrong?

Note:
Also I am imagining the problem as assigning 500 balls in 500 cells. And we are to find the probability that a particular cell has atmost 3 balls. Is this a good interpretation of the problem or not??

Comment: Why would the number of cases be $500^{500}$?

Comment: @String Each mistake will be either on page 1 or 2 or 3....500, so 500 ways. same for all 500 mistakes.

Comment: You are correct if the order of mistakes on any particular page matters.

Comment: Your method is not correct. Let's start with $500$ mistakes that must be spread over the book, and let's say that for a fixed mistake every page has equal chances to become the acceptor of this mistake. Then for a fixed page $i$ we are dealing with $500$ independent experiments that can succeed or fail. So binomial distribution must be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form a $500$-dimensional vector where each coordinate assigns mistake $k$ to page $x_k$:
$$
(x_1,...,x_{500})
$$
you are correct that there are $500^{500}$ such vectors. But if there are $3$ errors on page $i$ so that $x_a=x_b=x_c=i$, then changing the order of $a,b,c$ still points to the same three mistakes. It points to the same three coordinates of the vector above. Also all other $499$ pages apart from page $i$ are still available for the remaining mistakes/coordinates to be on. So instead you should use
$$
\binom{500}{3}\cdot 499^{500-3}
$$
which must be the number of ways to place exactly $3$ mistakes on page $i$.

Comment: I got another interesting solution to it by using the number of distinguishable arrangements of 500 undistinguishable balls in 500 cells.